# Setting Active Link jQuery

Tags: jquery, navigation

I have a link structure like this on my website...

```
index.php - homepage
index.php?section=  - other pages
```

here is a piece of code that I wrote to change the colour of the active link...

```
$(function(){
     var path = location.pathname.substring(1);
     if ( path )
          $('#nav ul#navigation li a[href$="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'selected');
});
```

but this doesn't take into account of PHP link structures, only flat file links. How would I get this working for links like `index.php?section=` as well as the basic links like `index.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class names instead of the full URL. It makes it a bit less wordy.

```
var path = document.location+""
path = path.split("?section=")
if(path.length>1) {
      $("."+path[1]).addClass('selected')
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<a class="section">...</a>
<a class="otherSection">...</a>
```

If you want be a bit less url-dependent, you can use a hash:

URL: http://yoursite.com?blabblah=xxx....#section1

Then use document.location.hash (which will = "section1") as the section indicator. It saves you the step of parsing the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it means alot to me but i already am using class names on some of the links, is it possible to still work with my link structure?

Comment: You can use multiple class names on elements, no problem.

Comment: Awesome, just tried it with class names and it works like a dream however the index.php without any parameters no longer works, any ideas for making both work would be incredible?

Comment: If there is no value, assume it is the home page and set the appropriate item accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try stripping out index.php?section= and use the contains selector (*=).

```
$(function() {
    var path = location.pathname.substring(1);

    if ( path.indexOf('?section=') ) {
        path = path.replace('index.php?section=', '');
    }

    if ( path )
        $('#nav ul#navigation li a[href*="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code doesn't seem to be doing anything for me, while my original code changed the colour of the home section but nothing else?

Comment: Can you post an example of the HTML that is being generated for the navigation?

Comment: <ul id="navigation">
 <li><a target="_self" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
 <li><a target="_self" href="index.php?section=news">News</a></li>
 <li><a target="_self" href="index.php?section=projects">Projects</a></li>
 <li><a target="_self" href="index.php?section=resume">Resume</a></li>
 <li><a target="_self" href="index.php?section=friends">Friends</a></li>
 <li><a target="_self" href="index.php?section=contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>